# ActiveAdmin display collection in Show method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have Packages, which have multiple Components (linked using a has_many through Bundles)

In ActiveAdmin, when I show a Package I want to be able to show all the Components linked to it

So I have a show method as follows:

```
show do
 attributes_table do
  row :description

  row 'Components' do |n|
     package.components.each do |component|
       #debugger
       component.name
     end
  end
 end
end
```

When I display the page, it shows the full version of each record, ie (one of which I show below, but there will be as many as there are Components):

```
[#<Component id: 2, component_token: "6e9be0b0-71c0-012f-d523-00254bca74c4", name: "Exercise Module", description: "This is the exercise module", created_at: "2012-04-26 11:25:20", updated_at: "2012-04-26 11:25:20">]
```

When I stop the debugger at the point I have commented it, the value for component.name is given as "Exercise Module", but that is not what is outputted to the show - in fact, ActiveAdmin seems to ignore everything in that |component| block.

How do I display the record attributes, and not the whole record itself?

Thanks

Comment: that throws a undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass error, though don't understand how concat would work

Comment: sometimes ActiveAdmin ignores everything in iterators, and it needs `concat`. Anyway found a better solution in the answer :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's happening because the row shows the output of this line `package.components.each {|component| ... }` and that's the collection

Try this:

```
show do

 attributes_table do
  row :description

  row 'Components' do |n|
     package.components.map(&:name).join("<br />").html_safe
  end
 end

end
```

or any other join string you prefer :)

Comment: That works, thanks, though I still don't understand why the |component| block doesn't spit out the values... but this will do me fine!

Comment: probably row just calls the block and renders whatever it returns, and in our case it returns the last line - all that the iterator returns. actually your example will work too if you change `each` to `map`, but you'll need to resolve some formatting issues